# Does the search in Microsoft Word have a proximity operator?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, office-for-mac, microsoft-word-2013

I need to search for a word within a certain number of words of another word. Is that possible in Microsoft Word?

For example,

```
word1 *3 word2
```

would return the results for 'word1' where it is 3 words away or less from 'word2'. If * was the desired proximity operator.

I use MS Word for the Mac 2011, but am curious if it is possible in any version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can use regular expressions to search in the newer versions of Word, see [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx). For some more information on how to get what you want using regular expressions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330781/regexp-words-apart

Comment: Thanks, @PaulHiemstra! It's great to know it supports reg. exp. I will be using this for sure. I haven't figured out how to do proximity searches yet, as described in the question, but I'm on the right path.

Comment: Word has had regular expressions for a long time, but Word's regex dialect is now very old, bears little relationship to regex syntax as it has developed elsewhere, and suffers from some additional gotchas. So be careful!

Answer (score 1):

While still not available in Word's native functionality, I've created an addin for Word called [Wordiscover](http://wordiscover.cint.io) that allows you to perform full regular expression find/replace, and proximity search.